# C# Regex append number after "$1"

Tags: c#, regex

```
extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_<DIST_N>[];
```

I want to replace the 'DIST_N' with '0' or '1', like:

```
extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_0[];
```

So I do something like this

```
    Regex REGEX_CODE_BLOCK_DIST_N = new Regex(@"(.+)(<DIST_N>)(.+)");
    int n = 0;
    string codeBlock = "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_<DIST_N>[];";
    string ret += REGEX_CODE_BLOCK_DIST_N.Replace(codeBlock, "$1" + n + "$3");
```

I only get this

```
$10[];// should be "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_0[];"
```

So how to append a number after "$1"?

Comment: "should be "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_0[];" that doesnt have a $1 ?

Comment: @AnuViswan, the $1 should be replace with "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_"

Comment: so, is your expected output be "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_$10$3[];"  or just "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_0[];"?

Comment: @AnuViswan "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_0[];" is what I expect

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly check if that resolves your issue

Comment: @AnuViswan I really do something stupid, thanks  a lot!

Comment: Can't you use just `codeBlock.Replace("<DIST_N>", 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex needs to be following as that is the string you are trying to replace.

```
"(<DIST_N>)"
```

Complete Code

```
Regex REGEX_CODE_BLOCK_DIST_N = new Regex(@"(<DIST_N>)");
int n = 0;
string codeBlock = "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_<DIST_N>[];";
string ret = REGEX_CODE_BLOCK_DIST_N.Replace(codeBlock,  n.ToString() );
```

Output

```
extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_0[];
```

Additional Comment

Please note you could use a more simpler string.Replace in this case, instead of using Regex.

```
string ret = codeBlock.Replace("<DIST_N>",  n.ToString());
```

Comment: Can't you use just `codeBlock.Replace("<DIST_N>", 0)`?

Comment: I agree, but the answer was more in line with the original OP. string replace would have been sufficient here. May be i could add it as comment

Answer (score 4):

In this simple case you can use string replace instead of a regex:

```
string codeBlock = "extern const BP_UINT8 g_SysMapDis_<DIST_N>[];";
string ret = codeBlock.Replace("<DIST_N>", "0");
```

Specifically in your case, your regex replacements string was `"$1" + n`, which has the value `"$10"` - so it ended up looking for the 10<sup>th</sup> group. The solution is to use `"${1}0"` instead, separating the group from the following `"0"`. For example:

```
var s = Regex.Replace("123abc",@"(.)","${1}0");
```

See also:

- [Working example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAIAYAEqCMBuAWACgNscA6AFQFMAPYcgJWoHMIAbAQzAFFaAHMNQDOwgJYB7KMMIkAzNgBMmAMKYA3sUzbsC3ADZsAFkwBZTmKgAKAJQatOx7iwBjCXGoAhdhJcBrTABeTAAiOmBqMChMN2lgTE8ABQB9AFUASQA5SgAOTBZkgGUAT2FzfgARMWFkgB4K9MLKZMyAPgBtAF08ENlHJxwsIXjgtw9vXz8man4uF2orEPrG5raQmFD0EJs+/u1cAE4rYZ3iBz2AN25MYSDMZhY6adnOecWcRTlOACMXddRUCErOQbOsQgASdQ4AC+W1ORD2+xwR2E8Mc0OI0KAA=)
- [Microsoft Docs - Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)